# Whether can we automate telecom based applications using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, telecommunication, pbx, sip-server

> My application is a telecom analytical product which can be
>   implemented as PBX system as well as call  center services. so how can i automate this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your system open in a browser you can.